# DOM timing or wrong code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two multi select list boxes, the first one allows someone to select a team.
The second one shows the members related to the team.  When the first list box (the team) is selected I make an ajax call to fill the members of that team.  I'm also using the chosen library.  This is all working fine however, I needed a way to remove the `x` from the listbox selected value so that users don't think they can remove a member from the team.

`$("#MainContent_lbMembers_chosen a").removeClass("search-choice-close");`

The above code works when I throw that in a console window, but if I have it in my if condition it doesnt seem to work:

```
$("#MainContent_lbTeams").on('change', function() {
            //was a value selected?
            var latest_value = $("option:selected:last", this).val();
            var latest_text = $("option:selected:last", this).text();

            if ($("#MainContent_lbTeams :selected").length > 0) {
                $("#dTeamNotice").show();
                $("#MainContent_lblTeamMembers").text("Members of '" + latest_text + "':");
                PopulateMembers(latest_value);
                $("#MainContent_lbMembers_chosen a").removeClass("search-choice-close");
                $("#trMembers").fadeIn();
            } else {
                //hide it...
                $("#dTeamNotice").css("display", "none");
                $("#trMembers").hide();
            }
        });
```

Basically the change event grabs the most recently selected text and value.  If the length of what is selected > 0 I load the members of my team with `PopulateMembers`:

```
 function PopulateMembers(buCompanyTeamID) {
        $('#<%=lbMembers.ClientID %>').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Loading...</option>');
         $("#<%=lbMembers.ClientID %>").trigger("chosen:updated");
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/Code/WebServices/Utilities.asmx/GetTeamMembers",
             data: '{buCompanyTeamID: ' + buCompanyTeamID + '}',
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: OnMembersPopulated,
             failure: function (response) {
                 alert(response.d);
             }
         });
     }

     function OnMembersPopulated(response) {
         PopulateControl(response.d, $("#<%=lbMembers.ClientID %>"), true);
     }

    function PopulateControl(list, control, selected) {
        if (list.length > 0) {
            control.removeAttr("disabled");
            control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0"></option>');
            $.each(list, function () {
                if(selected)
                    control.append($("<option selected></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                else
                    control.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        }
        else {
            control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0"><option>');
        }
        control.trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
```

But I cannot understand why in a console window I can do this:

`$("#MainContent_lbMembers_chosen a").removeClass("search-choice-close");`

And it removes the `x` from the chosen selected value so that a user cannot remove an item, but within the if condition this doesnt have any effect.

I even tried disabling like so:

`$("#MainContent_lbMembers").attr('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");`

This only works in a console as well, is it some timing issue or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PopulateMembers()` contains an asynchronous Ajax call.  So, if you are expecting:

```
PopulateMembers(latest_value);
$("#MainContent_lbMembers_chosen a").removeClass("search-choice-close");
```

to operate on the results of the ajax call in `PopulateMembers()`, then you do indeed have a timing problem.  The Ajax call will complete some time in the future, long after `PopulateMembers()` has finished and long after you've executed the `.removeClass()` statement.

To operate on the results of `PopulateMembers()`, you have to either put your code in the success handler of that ajax call or restructure your code so that `PopulateMembers()` will call a callback when it's done and you can do the `.removeClass()` in that callback.

---

I would suggest using promises like this:

```
// return the ajax promise from PopulateMembers
function PopulateMembers(buCompanyTeamID) {
     $('#<%=lbMembers.ClientID %>').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Loading...</option>');
     $("#<%=lbMembers.ClientID %>").trigger("chosen:updated");
     return $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/Code/WebServices/Utilities.asmx/GetTeamMembers",
         data: '{buCompanyTeamID: ' + buCompanyTeamID + '}',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json"
     }).then(onMembersPopulated, function (response) {
             alert(response.d);
     });
 }

 $("#MainContent_lbTeams").on('change', function() {
        //was a value selected?
        var latest_value = $("option:selected:last", this).val();
        var latest_text = $("option:selected:last", this).text();

        if ($("#MainContent_lbTeams :selected").length > 0) {
            $("#dTeamNotice").show();
            $("#MainContent_lblTeamMembers").text("Members of '" + latest_text + "':");
            // act only when the returned promise is resolved
            PopulateMembers(latest_value).then(function() {
                $("#MainContent_lbMembers_chosen a").removeClass("search-choice-close");
                $("#trMembers").fadeIn();
            });
        } else {
            //hide it...
            $("#dTeamNotice").css("display", "none");
            $("#trMembers").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @JonH - I added a suggested fix using promises.

Comment: hmm now Im getting undefined function for PopulateMembers.

Comment: @JonH - typo in my answer, fixed.  You should be able to identify syntax errors by looking at the error console.